# Angular 2 build --prod fails "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'"

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

In below code `this.fb` is `FormBuilder` instance

```
return this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  phone: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  website: ['', [<any>Validators.pattern(web_pattern)]]
  tax_code: ['', [<any>Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(50)]],

  owner: this.fb.group({
    first_name: ['', [<any>Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]],
    last_name: ['', [<any>Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]],
    phone: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  })

});
```

On building this code using `ng build --prod`, it fails stating : **Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'**.
It is having problem with `owner` key, which is a `FormGroup` instance, instead of `FormControl`. However according to angular docs its valid to add a `FormGroup` within a `FormGroup`.

This code builds perfectly without `--prod`. 
I understand that `--prod` leads to strict typechecking. I am not able to understand how to correct this.

Comment: Can you add template for this component?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: I think yurzui is on the right track. It's probably something in your html, something like `form.controls.owner.controls.first_name` could become `form.controls.owner['controls'].first_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some where in your Form Control you must be using some thing like this

```
form.get('qualifications').controls
```

or `form.controls.qualifications.controls.degree` or
 `form.controls.qualifications['controls'].degree` and this is not `aot` friendly.

You need to put this inside the component instead of the template Something like this.

**Template**

```
 <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor = "let address of getAddresses(user) ; let i = index">
```

**Component**

```
  getAddresses(form){
    return form.get('addresses').controls;
  }
```

A [**working**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) aot example of the same and [**code**](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/reactive/reactive.component.html)